# implementing "not equal to " loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

i have a simple problem i am quite new to matlab so i am having problem in implementing it i have two 64x2 matrices u and h.i have to check if a single row in u is not equal to all of the rows in h.then the row which is not equal should be saved in a separate matrix meanwhile i have written this code but  what it does is that r(i,:) get all the values of u(i,:) when this code runs, what i want is that only those values of u(i,:) should be stored in r which are not similar to any row in h matrix.

```
h=[];
for j=1:8
    for i=1:8
        h=[h; i j];
    end
end
u=[5.3,1.4;6,8;2,3;3,5.5;2.6,8;3.7,2;4,2;5,3;1.9,8;5.4,4;3.2,3;2,2;2,4;2,3;8,2.2;8,4;7.3,1.5;6.2,5.1;2.4,1.5;3,5;2,7.1;1.8,2.7;3,4;6,5;6,1;5,4;4,6;3.5,2;5,7;7.2,8;7,7;5,5;6,3;6,6;1,2;5,8;3,5;1,5;2,2;2,1;6,3;4,7;6,8;3,6;1,6;5,2;3,5;8,7;8,4;4,8;1,1;6,3;7,5;8,1;1,6;4,5;5,5;6,7;6,7;6,7;6,3;3,4;5,7;1,1]
for i=1
    for j=1:64
  if u(i,:)==h(j,:)
 c=1
  else 
      c=0
       if c==0
               r(i,:)=u(i,:)
       end
  end
    end
end
```

can anyone help me please

Comment: i was trying to do it with another loop using not equal to as u(i,:)~=h(j,:) but could not give any better results

Comment: Condition in the `if` statement should be scalar. Use `all(u(i,:)==h(j,:))` or `isequal(u(i,:), h(j,:)`.

Comment: i have tried but it is giving the same answer, i get all values of u in r matrix whereas i need only those values of u which are not present in h matrix

Comment: do you have something against formatting, capital I, and/or punctuation? Please format your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one line with `ismember`:

```
r = u(~ismember(u,h,'rows'),:);
```

With your example data, the result is

```
>> r    
r =   
    5.3000    1.4000
    3.0000    5.5000
    2.6000    8.0000
    3.7000    2.0000
    1.9000    8.0000
    5.4000    4.0000
    3.2000    3.0000
    8.0000    2.2000
    7.3000    1.5000
    6.2000    5.1000
    2.4000    1.5000
    2.0000    7.1000
    1.8000    2.7000
    3.5000    2.0000
    7.2000    8.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

use `setdiff` with `'rows'` option to compute `r`. Please avoid unnecessary loops. pre-allocate when possible.

```
% construct h without loop
[h{1} h{2}]=ndgrid(1:8,1:8);
h=[h{1}(:) h{2}(:)];
% get r using setdiff
r = setdiff( u, h, 'rows')
```

Results with

```
r =
1.8000    2.7000
1.9000    8.0000
2.0000    7.1000
2.4000    1.5000
2.6000    8.0000
3.0000    5.5000
3.2000    3.0000
3.5000    2.0000
3.7000    2.0000
5.3000    1.4000
5.4000    4.0000
6.2000    5.1000
7.2000    8.0000
7.3000    1.5000
8.0000    2.2000
```

Comment: setdiff is nice, although it has complexity NlogN !

Answer (score 0):

Solution of you question in NlogN complexity (N=64):

```
N=size(h,1);
[husorted,origin_husorted,destination_hu]=unique([h;u],'rows','first');
iduplicates=destination_hu(N+1:end)<=destination_hu(N),:);
r=u;
r(iduplicates,:)=0;
```

`destination_uh` is the only output of `unique` that is useful; It verifies `[h;u]=husorted(destination_uh,:)]`. `'first'` ensures that if line `i` of `u` is equal line `j` of `h`, then `destination_uh(i+N)` is equal to `destination_uh(j)`.

Solution for your particular h, with complexity N:

```
r=u;
r(all(u==round(u)&u>=1&u<=8,2),:)=0;
```